# Show form at bottom-right corner of desktop without overlaping Taskbar

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I'm trying to make my program **always in top**, the problem is, if I set "Topmost" to True, it automatically *covers my icons* bar. I tried to change the size of form and the location, but no matter what, It always cover the task bar.

***Images:***

With `TopMost` = True:

[image: Topmost = True]

With `TopMost` = False:

[image: Topmost = False]

I need it to perform like `Topmost = True` but looks like `Topmost = False`

Comment: Yea, I did that

`Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - GP_0.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.GP_Cmds.Height - (qtd_contas * Me.Controls("GP_0").Height))`... Look at the pictures, both have this same line of code, but when I use "Topmost = True" it simply covers my taks bar.

Comment: Wel, you're not correctly calculating the area occupied by your Form. You have a black band at the bottom side, that's what's covering the toolbar. Remove it or add it to the Form's height.

Comment: That's true, I was using "Me.Location" but I've to use "Me.Size", I made some changes and It's working now! Thanks a lot.